# Can this query be optimized somehow?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Is this is a good query in performance or I can somehow optimize this query? I need to select date column from rental_schedules table and count how many available same dates are available (rental_schedule_status = 1):

```
$reservationTimes = RentalSchedule::distinct()
        ->select('date',
        DB::raw('(SELECT count(date) FROM rental_schedules AS r2 
        WHERE r2.date = rental_schedules.date and rental_schedule_status = 1) as free_time'))
        ->where('premises_id', $id)->pluck('free_time', 'date');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to phrase your query using left join to a subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT
    rs1.date,
    COALESCE(rs2.cnt, 0) AS free_time
FROM rental_schedules rs1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM rental_schedules
    WHERE rental_schedule_status = 1
    GROUP BY date
) rs2
    ON rs1.date = rs2.date
WHERE
    rs1.premises_id = ?;
```

Your updated Laravel code:

```
$reservationTimes = RentalSchedule:from("RentalSchedule AS rs1")
    ->select(DB::raw('rs1.date, COALESCE(rs2.cnt, 0) AS free_time'))
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                     FROM rental_schedules
                     WHERE rental_schedules_status = 1
                     GROUP BY date) rs2'),
    function($join) {
        $join->on('rs1.date', '=', 'rs2.date');
     })
->where('premises_id', $id)
->pluck('free_time', 'date');
```

You may also try adding an index on `(rental_schedules_status, date)`, to speed up the subquery:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON rental_schedules (rental_schedules_status, date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get result without join or subquery :

Try this :

```
$reservationTimes = RentalSchedule::select('date',\DB::Raw("sum(case when rental_schedule_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as free_time"))
                ->where('premises_id', $id)
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->get()
                ->pluck('free_time', 'date');
```